# Are these two expressions about $\epsilon$ equivalent?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b\in \Bbb R$, are $|a-b|<\epsilon$ equivalent to $|a-b|\le\epsilon$ ?
Or is any inequalities with $\epsilon$ in it strictly less or strictly large?

Comment: I don't think this question should necessarily be tagged under real analysis & calculus. This is more like Pre-Calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Of course they are not equivalent. It is true though that one can replace $<\epsilon$ with $\leq \epsilon$ in definitions of continuity, limits etc.

Comment: How these two different? they both represent $a=b$. I am confusing.

Comment: What you mean to say is this: If $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy ($\forall \epsilon>0$, $|a-b|<\epsilon$), then this implies $a=b$. The same is true if we replace "$<\epsilon$" with "$\leq \epsilon$". But this was not your question